# SP2010: add new wiki page containing default data

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, wiki, wiki-pages

Is it possible to add a new wiki page, that contains default data, in my document library?
The data is made in htmlcode.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page layout and use that as the default or choose it in the ribbon for specific pages.  I did something where I created a table of contents with html on a page layout and used that as my default.

Comment: When i create a new page layout for wiki pages, can i still create a blank wiki page?

Comment: Yes you can.  You can still use the same default if you'd like and only when you want to use your custom one go up to the page ribbon -> page actions -> page layout and select which one you want to use there.